# Unity - Canvas element active by default even though it's set to inactive in the script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

The pause menu is getting shown by default when I click the play button, even though the GameIsPaused boolean is set to false, I don't know if it's the fault of how I referenced it in the engine itself or how the script is written.

Here's how I referenced it in Unity:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (!GameIsPaused)
            {
                Pause();
            }
            else
            {
                Resume();
            }
        }
    }
    

    public void Resume()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        GameIsPaused = false;
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
    void Pause()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        GameIsPaused = true;
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }
    public void LoadMenu()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading Game...");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }
    public void QuitGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Quitting Game...");
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of frame update. Before even setting the variable true in the called function, the else block runs. Try moving the bool to the if condition itself.